# Can a memory leak cause the browser to freeze?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, single-page-application, freeze

I have a situation where if someone leaves my SPA running for upwards of 15 minutes without interacting with it, the browser freezes. The UI is still visible, but not responsive. The tab has to be closed and re-opened. I've profiled using Chrome's performance tab, and I don't have any runaway timers or loops, so my guess is the problem is a memory leak.

My question is, does that make sense? Would a browser tab freeze after running out of memory? It seems more like something I would expect from 100% CPU usage.

Edit: This is on Chrome/Windows, on a customer's machine, so I haven't been able to see it in action (yet).

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends. *Is* the browser using a lot of memory? Have you checked the task manager, at least?

Comment: Yes. 100%; It comes down to the features you run and the browser support. In my development experience I find most instability to come from mozilla's firefox. Chrome may hang but it recovers well. But no browser is perfect, I'd say it comes down to the animation frames. If browser is in focus no issues, but you tab out or move around such timer goes to 1fps vs your thought 60fps so there's catch up? Weird stuff can happen let's just say. :D